# Looping to get all combination using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, plyr, reshape2

Here it is my data

```
## Data
datex <- c(rep("2021-01-18", 61), rep("2021-01-19", 125))
hourx <- c(0,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,16,10,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16)
seller <- c("dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp1","dombsdpapp2","dombsdpapp2")
product <- c("00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021459","00021459","00021459","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460","00021460")
detail <- c("E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","notEnoughBalance","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","E99","notEnoughBalance","E99","success","success","success","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","E99","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","success","E99","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","E99","success","success","notEnoughBalance","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","success","notEnoughBalance","E99","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","success","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","notEnoughBalance","E99","E99","success","E99","success","success","E99","E99","success","success","E99")
status <- c("FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK01","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK01","FI04","OK00","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","OK01","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK01","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK01","FI04","FI04","OK00","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04","FI04","OK00","OK00","FI04")
channel <- c("f2","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f3","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f3","f3","f2","f3","f3","f3","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2","f2")
transaction <- c(1,120,50,5,1,2,1,9,6,12,5,25,14,6,22,9,10,14,15,12,220,12,12,14,9,11,100,90,110,12,13,4,3,1,2,3,3,5,7,5,5,6,9,16,8,13,10,20,15,18,10,19,15,5,13,12,10,12,26,14,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,4,0,6,8,0,2,3,0,2,0,1,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,1,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,6,5,2,0,8,0,0,12,11,0,2,0,11,0,0,14,21,0,0,13,7,0,17,0,0,18,0,7,0,4,4,0,0,7,12,0,13,0,0,130,160,9,0,0,0,16,0,0,16,0,14,0,0,9,0,11,8,0,8,0,0,8,0,10,5,0,15,0,0,3,0,0,8,8,0,0,6,5,0,8,0,0,5,1,0,0,95)
mydatax <- data.frame(datex, hourx, seller, product, detail, status, channel, transaction)
```

My task is to find outliers from any combination in my data using tsoutliers package. for sample, i use two combinations. 1st combination:

- seller = "dombsdpapp1"
- product = "00021460"
- detail = "E99"
- status = "FI04"
- channel = "f2"

```
# Process 1
library(tsoutliers)
combination1 <- subset(mydatax, seller == "dombsdpapp1" &
                         product == "00021460" &
                         detail == "E99" &
                         status == "FI04" &
                         channel == "f2")

model.anomaly1 <- tso(as.ts(combination1$transaction))
find.anomaly.index1 <- subset(model.anomaly1$outliers, coefhat > 0)[,2]
data.anomaly1 <- combination1[find.anomaly.index1,]
data.anomaly1

#datex hourx      seller  product detail status channel transaction
#2   2021-01-18     1 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         120
#27  2021-01-18    14 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         100
#29  2021-01-18    16 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         110
#139 2021-01-19    10 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         130
```

2nd combination:

- seller = "dombsdpapp2"
- product = "00021460"
- detail = "E99"
- status = "FI04"
- channel = "f2"

```
# Process 2
library(tsoutliers)
combination2 <- subset(mydatax, seller == "dombsdpapp2" &
                         product == "00021460" &
                         detail == "E99" &
                         status == "FI04" &
                         channel == "f2")

model.anomaly2 <- tso(as.ts(combination2$transaction))
find.anomaly.index2 <- subset(model.anomaly2$outliers, coefhat > 0)[,2]
data.anomaly2 <- combination2[find.anomaly.index2,]
data.anomaly2

#datex hourx      seller  product detail status channel transaction
#140 2021-01-19    10 dombsdpapp2 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         160
#186 2021-01-19    16 dombsdpapp2 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          95
```

After that, All looping insert into 1 table:

```
my.anomaly.result <- rbind(data.anomaly1, data.anomaly2)
my.anomaly.result

#         datex hourx      seller  product detail status channel transaction
#2   2021-01-18     1 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         120
#27  2021-01-18    14 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         100
#29  2021-01-18    16 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         110
#139 2021-01-19    10 dombsdpapp1 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         130
#140 2021-01-19    10 dombsdpapp2 00021460    E99   FI04      f2         160
#186 2021-01-19    16 dombsdpapp2 00021460    E99   FI04      f2          95
```

The painfull point is how do i loop all process to get All Result using dplyr? Because i have 100K Combinations. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In data there are certain groups with only 1 or 2 rows. For such groups `tso` functions returns an error. I have a written a custom function where I have set a threshold of 5 rows. So if a group has less than 5 rows, all the rows of that group are selected for rest of them we apply the function. You can adjust this 5 to any number as per your data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tsoutliers)

get_outlier_index <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) < 5) return(seq_along(x))
  model.anomaly <- tso(as.ts(x))
  model.anomaly$outliers$ind[model.anomaly$outliers$coefhat > 0]
}

mydatax %>%
  group_by(across(seller:channel)) %>%
  slice(get_outlier_index(transaction)) %>%
  ungroup

#   datex      hourx seller      product  detail           status channel transaction
#   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    <chr>            <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>
# 1 2021-01-18     7 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99              FI04   f3               25
# 2 2021-01-18    11 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99              FI04   f3              220
# 3 2021-01-19     5 dombsdpapp1 00021459 E99              FI04   f3                6
# 4 2021-01-18    10 dombsdpapp1 00021459 notEnoughBalance OK01   f3               12
# 5 2021-01-18     1 dombsdpapp1 00021460 E99              FI04   f2              120
# 6 2021-01-18    14 dombsdpapp1 00021460 E99              FI04   f2              100
# 7 2021-01-18    16 dombsdpapp1 00021460 E99              FI04   f2              110
# 8 2021-01-19    10 dombsdpapp1 00021460 E99              FI04   f2              130
# 9 2021-01-19    11 dombsdpapp1 00021460 notEnoughBalance OK01   f2                0
#10 2021-01-18    11 dombsdpapp2 00021459 notEnoughBalance OK01   f3                0
#11 2021-01-19    14 dombsdpapp2 00021459 notEnoughBalance OK01   f3                0
#12 2021-01-19    10 dombsdpapp2 00021460 E99              FI04   f2              160
#13 2021-01-19    16 dombsdpapp2 00021460 E99              FI04   f2               95
#14 2021-01-19    11 dombsdpapp2 00021460 notEnoughBalance OK01   f2                0
```

Comment: Thanks sir, it works!!!. But sir, some combination have error in tso function, do you know the trick to remove those some combinations? so we don't need to run the tso function on them? Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Is there some specific property in the combinations that has an error so that we can remove them beforehand? Maybe you can use `tryCatch` and return 0 from the function if the error occurs.

Comment: That's the problem sir, some errors from function "auto.arima", because "tso" function uses "auto.arima" to detect outliers. How do i use tryCatch sir, can you write it down for me? I'm not good enough on Error Handling 